# How to model Max-Cut as ILP

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, cplex, combinatorial-optimization, graphs

I want to model [Max-Cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) in IBM's CPLEX, but I fail at modeling the objective function.
My attempt is to use is to sum the XOR of inclusion for vertices of each edge, as exactly then an edge is included in the cut. But I don't see a way to use XOR.

Is there another way to model Max-Cut that is feasible in CPLEX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ and $E$ be the sets of vertices and edges respectively. Define a binary variable $x_v$ for each vertex $v\in V$ to be 1 if the vertex is on the "left" side of the cut and 0 if it is on the "right" side. Define a variable $y_{(i,j)}\in [0,1]$ for each edge $(i,j)\in E.$ (You can make $y$ either binary or continuous.) Your objective function is to maximize $$\sum_{(i,j)\in E} y_{(i,j)}$$and your constraints are $$y_{(i,j)}\le x_i + x_j \quad \forall (i,j)\in E$$ and $$y_{(i,j)}\le 2 - x_i - x_j \quad \forall (i,j)\in E.$$

Comment: It turns out that these are exactly the constraints that arise somewhat automatically from rewriting $y_{(i,j)} \implies ((x_i \lor x_j) \land \neg (x_i \land x_j))$ in conjunctive normal form.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Looks obvious now that I see it.

Comment: same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72592970/ibm-cplex-use-xor-in-objective-function/72598777#72598777

Comment: @AlexFleischer I posted there first as I didn't this community existed. Is the policy to delete the post in the less specific community?

Comment: Hi, no problem. I guess next time the idea is not to cross post. All the best

Comment: @MoritzGroß If you do cross-post (for instance, because you post in one forum and after a number of days still have no answer), it is considered polite to note on each forum that you cross-posted on the other forum (with a link). The main idea, I think, is to avoid people wasting time answering a question that has already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: @prubin One last question: Is there a paper that introduced this ILP-formulation that I should cite when I use it?

Comment: I'm sure there is a paper somewhere that first introduced an ILP formulation for the problem, and I would not be shocked if the formulation looked like this, but I have no idea what the paper is. You could probably just describe it as "a typical formulation" or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

To start with maxcut, you can start with the [maxcut example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/maxcut.mod) in [how to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/) ?

```
int n=400;
range r=1..n;

// Random graph  
float edge_prob=0.5;
int  weight_range=10;
int big=100000;
 
tuple t
{
  int i;
  int j;
}

{t} s={<i,j> | ordered i,j in r};

int w[i in r][j in r]=(i<=j)?((rand(big)<=big*edge_prob)?rand(weight_range):0):0;

// end of random graph

//int n=4;
//range r=1..n;
//float w[r][r]=
//
//[[ 0. , 8. ,-9. , 0.],
// [ 8. , 0. , 7. , 9.],
// [-9. , 7.  ,0., -8.],
// [ 0. , 9., -8. , 0.]];

assert card(s)==n*(n-1) div 2;

 // x is the unknown and 0 or 1 means in one or the other side of the fence
 dvar boolean x[r];
 
 dexpr float obj=2*sum(<i,j> in s) w[i][j]*x[i]*(1-x[j]);
 
 maximize obj;
 
 subject to
 {
   
 }
 
 {int} x1={i| i in r:x[i]==1};
 
 execute
 {
   writeln("objective = ",obj);
   writeln("x set to 1 : ",x1);
 }
```